# Why is the `apply` function not able to detect and act upon numeric columns of a data.frame?

Tags: r, apply, sapply

There is a strange behavior of `apply` when I am trying to conditionally apply a function based on the data type of my column.

Here is the function. It checks for the `class()` and then performs a suitable operation.

```
sampleF <- function(x){
  DT = ifelse(class(x) == "numeric" | class(x) == "integer","Numbers",
              ifelse(class(x) == "character" | class(x) == "factor","Text","Others"))
  return(DT)
}
```

I am trying to apply that on the below data.frame and getting an incorrect output.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = letters[1:5],Col2 = 1:5,Col3 = as.factor(c("A","B","A","C","A")))
```

Output :

```
apply(df1,2,FUN = sampleF)
    Col1   Col2   Col3 
    "Text" "Text" "Text"
```

`sapply` on the other hand, gives the correct output

```
sapply(df1,sampleF)
     Col1      Col2      Col3 
   "Text" "Numbers"    "Text"
```

What might be the reason for such a behavior of `apply` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use `lapply` for applying functions on columns in a `data.frame` or to some extent `sapply`.  But, with `apply`, it coerces the output to `matrix` and it can hold only a single class.  So, if there are any `character` element, even numeric columns gets converts to `character` class.

```
out <- lapply(df1, sampleF)
unlist(out)
#   Col1      Col2      Col3 
#   "Text" "Numbers"    "Text"
```

---

Also, as the `length` of `class` is 1, we can use `if/else` or `switch` instead of `ifelse`

```
sampleF1 <- function(x){
        cls <- class(x)
        switch(cls,
           numeric = "Numbers",
                 integer = "Numbers",
                 character = "Text",
                 factor = "Text",
                  "Others")
 }


 df2 <- cbind(df1, Col4 = TRUE)
 lapply(df2, sampleF1)
 #$Col1
 #[1] "Text"

 #$Col2
 #[1] "Numbers"

 #$Col3
 #[1] "Text"

 #$Col4
 #[1] "Others"
```